# Como montar uma matriz com vetores de tamanhos diferentes no R?

Tags: r, matriz, séries-temporais

Estou tentando montar uma matriz com vetores de diferentes tamanhos. Para operacionalizar isso, tentei o seguinte código em R:

```
ST_Nile <- Nile
n <- length(ST_Nile) # tamanho da série temporal
k <- 5 # passos de previsão
qtde_modelos <- 6
m <- c(rep(NA,qtde_modelos))
t <- c(rep(NA,qtde_modelos)) # comprimento do vetor de treinamento
TrainNile <- c(rep(NA,95))
Matriz_train <- matrix(ncol = max(t), nrow = qtde_modelos, byrow = TRUE)

for (i in 1:qtde_modelos) {
  if (i==1) {
    m[i] <- 30
  } else { m[i] <- m[i-1] - k}
  t[i] <- n - m[i]
  TrainNile[i] <- ST_Nile[1:t[i]]
  if (length(TrainNile[i])==95) {
    Matriz_train <- append(Matriz_train[i,],TrainNile[i])
  } else{
    TrainNile[i] = c(TrainNile[i], rep(NA, 95 - length(TrainNile[i])))
    Matriz_train <- append(Matriz_train[i,],TrainNile[i])
  }
}
```

É aí que surge a dúvida do título porque obtenho o erro **"number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"**. Alguma ideia de como preencher essa matriz?

Comment: Se `t` é inicializado com `NA`'s, então `max(t)` é `NA` e não 95.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, você está correto. Fiz a alteração, obrigado. Quanto ao preenchimento da matriz, você me indicaria algum procedimento?

Comment: Não seria melhor criar `TrainNile` como lista e converter para matriz no final se necessário?

Comment: Vou testar isso @CarlosEduardoLagosta. Obrigado!